# Set visibility of DataGridView columns using CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing a windows form application manipulating a SQL Server database. When I click a combobox that is filled with all tables, I add every columns from the selected table in checkedlistbox and than when I check the following column to disappear. I'm stuck here.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var tableName = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}", form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True"));

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dataTable);

        string comboQuery = $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{tableName}'";

        using (form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True"))
        {
            form1.conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comboQuery, form1.conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add((string)reader["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                    }
                }
            }

            form1.conn.Close();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Thank you, for the invested time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have the columns in `DataGridView`, you don't need to load them again from SQL server and as already is shown in the other answer, you can get the column names from `DataGridView`.

To add the columns to `CheckedListBox`, I prefer to use `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to show the column `HeaderText` in `CheckedListBox`, while having access to their names to be able find them in `DataGridView`.

Then I'd set the initial check state of the items based on the visibility of their corresponding column.

Then I's handle `ItemCheck` event and find the column name based on the checked item and will set the column visibility based on the new check state:

```
//Add the columns to checked list box
var columns = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.HeaderText }).ToList();
checkedListBox1.DataSource = columns;
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "HeaderText";

//Set initial check state based on columns visibility
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dynamic item = checkedListBox1.Items[i];
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, dataGridView1.Columns[(string)item.Name].Visible);
}

//Hanlde ItemCheck event
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += (obj, args) =>
{
    dynamic item = checkedListBox1.Items[args.Index];
    var visible = args.NewValue == CheckState.Checked ? true : false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[(string)item.Name].Visible = visible;
};
```

[image]

Just in case you are interested to do so using a `ContextMenuStrip`:

```
//Add the columns to context menu strip
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(c.HeaderText);
    item.Tag = c.Name;
    item.Checked = c.Visible;
    item.CheckOnClick = true;

    //Hanlde CheckStateChanged event of context menu strip items
    item.CheckStateChanged += (obj, args) =>
    {
        var i = (ToolStripMenuItem)obj;
        dataGridView1.Columns[(string)i.Tag].Visible = i.Checked;
    };
}

//Show context menu strip on right click on data grid veiw header
dataGridView1.CellMouseClick += (obj, args) =>
{
    if (args.RowIndex == -1 && args.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
};
```

[image]

Comment: But when I change the value to different table they're all saved, and if I have for Example in the first table 'ID' and in the Second 'Name' and 'Number' they are all saved in the ToolStripMenu, and I only need for the selected table.

Comment: If you put the code in `Load` event handler of your form and have a `dataGridView1` and `contextMenuStrip1` it will work properly. Right? It means for `dataGridView2`, it needs `contextMenuStrip2`.

Comment: Well I have made the code that way, when you select a item from the table combo box datagridview changes with the chosen table. But when I select other table stripmenu from the first is saved and I have all values in that menu.

Comment: I can imagine some possible mistakes in the code but I'm not sure about your code. let's keep this post as it is (since this piece of the code is complimentary for the post  and it's not the main answer to your question) and ask a new question including [MCVE] to reproduce the problem and describe the expected behavior, then I or maybe another community member will help you to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by filling the `CheckedListBox` maybe like this:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Clear   
checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                                                    .ToArray());

for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
```

Now you can maybe code the `checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible =
       checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked;
}
```

**Update** Reza found the `ItemCheck` event; not sure how I missed it ;-). This is obviously much better as it doesn't need to go over all Items..